# "Why wouldn't I?" vs "Why couldn't I?"

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

What is the grammatically correct response to the question "Can you see me?":

"Of course I can, why **couldn't I**?"

Or

"Of course I can, why **wouldn't I**?"

To me the second one seems correct, but I can't find a proper *grammatical rule* for why that is so. Since **could** is based on the ability of a person to do something it kind of fits the context, but it doesn't sound correct to me. **Would**, on the other hand, represents willingness rather than ability to do something so it doesn't fit the context, but sounds right.

The only reason to my mind why using **would** is the correct way is because it is in the form of question and therefore implying a hypothetical situation wherein lies an unknown condition which is the reason why one person would not be able to see the other.

Any advice?

Comment: "Can you see me?" can mean multiple things: it could literally mean "am I visible to you?" for instance if you're on a video chat. Or it could be asking a doctor, advisor, counsellor or other person if they have time to speak to you in a professional way. The response depends on what you mean.

Comment: @StuartF I mean in a literal sense "am I visible to you".

Comment: @MichaelMunta You should add that in the question for clarity, without needing to read through comments.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct and both functionally ask the same question.

You need to consider all definitions of *would*.  One of those definitions is *(expressing the conditional mood) indicating the consequence of an imagined event or situation.*  *Wouldn't*, in your example, expresses the conditional mood.

In your examples *wouldn't* merely asks, *What imagined situation might prevent me from seeing you?*

Couldn't asks *What things might prevent me from seeing you?*

In your example, however, the two words mean the same thing. The asker is not concerned with drawing distinctions between situations and things. The asker merely asks, *Why might I not be able to see you?*  The choice of wouldn't or couldn't is without consequence.

Answer (score 3):

This is literally just the difference between '*wouldn't*' and '*couldn't*'.

The suggested meanings in context would be:

- why couldn't I? (*what external factors could prevent me?*)
- why wouldn't I? (*why would I not choose to?*)